# express-js type error , app.listen is not a function

Tags: node.js

My current code looks like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express;

app.listen(3000,  () => {
  console.log("project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
})

const Discord = require("Discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSSAGES"]});

client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === "wanna hear a joke") {
    message.channel.send("Shut up.")
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token);
```

and when i went to test it, it says TypeError: app.listen is not a function

it should've work but it keeps doing it

Answer (score 1):

Be brave and don't give up, you only need to add `()` to `express` on the 2nd line like this:

Before:

> const app = express;

After:

> const app = express();